# error in baking database in cake php

Tags: php, cakephp

[image: Whenever I hit d the menu repeats itself]

I have created my database and edited my database in config file. I have filled database.config with the required details and my localhost/cakephp is also completely green but I dont know what is wrong. Below is my database coding in config.

```
<?php

class DATABASE_CONFIG {
    public $test = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'user',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'test_database_name',
    );
    public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'MyKitchen',
    );
}
```

Comment: every thing is right in your database there is no problem change the name of `database.config` to `database.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove (,)   comma after array end , as display below,

```
public $test = array(
            'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'login' => 'user',
            'password' => 'password',
            'database' => 'test_database_name' // remove (,) comma 
        );
        public $default = array(
            'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'login' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'database' => 'MyKitchen'  // remove (,) comma 
        );
```